# How to save in a file all rows that have equal value for a column

Tags: python

I wrote a python script that generates a dictionary from a CIF file. I tested it with a file like this [[1qpe](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=cif&compression=NO&structureId=1QPE), with 4105 lines -> time: 383ms (milliseconds)] or this ([1d66](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=cif&compression=NO&structureId=1D66), with 3274 lines -> time: 225ms), but when I try it with this one ([4tvx](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=cif&compression=NO&structureId=4TVX), with 170925 lines), it takes a very long time, to the point that I resolve to block the process. I thought then to split the CIF file, extrapolating from it the lines that start with ATOM and HETATM:

In practice, starting from every original CIF file, the intention was to obtain 4 files, initially:

1. a file that contains what I call header = all rows above the loop of lines that start with ATOM and HETATM
2. a file that contains the only 26 lines of the loop
3. a file that contains all the rows that start with ATOM and HETATM
4. a file that contains all the remaining lines, which I call footer

Up here I solved, taking 34ms for 1d66, 43ms for 1qpe, and 1.923s for 4tvx.
Now, got the third file (goal of all this process, because is the input of the dictionary), I want to extrapolate from it all the rows that have the same seventh column, writing them in a dedicated file saved with the value of the column 7 as filename, repeating this for all the values of the column 7.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
import os.path
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cif_dir = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'cif/')

def get_line_number(phrase, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if phrase in line:
                return i

def my_header_splitfile(infilepath, chunksize):
    fname, ext = infilepath.rsplit('.',1)
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        outfilepath = "{}_header.{}".format(fname, ext)
        with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in (infile.readline() for _ in range(0,(chunksize-2))):
                outfile.write(line) # END
    temp_lines = open(infilepath).readlines()
    temp_outfilepath = "{}_temp.{}".format(fname, ext)
    atom_hetatm_header_outfilepath = "{}_atom_hetatm_header.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(atom_hetatm_header_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(temp_lines[(chunksize-2):(chunksize+25)])
    with open(temp_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(temp_lines[(chunksize+25):-1]) # END
    footer_lines = open(temp_outfilepath).readlines()
    footer_outfilepath = "{}_footer.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(footer_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in footer_lines:
            if not (line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('HETATM')):
                outfile.writelines(line) # END
    temp_atom_hetatm_lines = open(temp_outfilepath).readlines()
    temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath = "{}_atom_hetatm.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in temp_atom_hetatm_lines:
            if (line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('HETATM')):
                outfile.writelines(line) # END
    os.remove(temp_outfilepath) # FINISH
    """BEGIN TO SPLIT THE 'ATOM'"""
    """
    with open(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath,'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()

        rows_list = list()
        chains_list = list()
        for line in lines:
            col = line.split(None)
            rows_list.append(col)
            #print line
            #if col[0] == "HETATM":
            #   print "HETATM record"
            if col[0] == "ATOM":
                #print col[0]
                # FILTER FOR ONLY PROTEINS AND NUCLEIC ACIDS
                if (col[3] == "N" or col[3] == "N1"):
                    chains_list.append(col[6])
                    chains_list_cleaned = list(set(chains_list))
                    for chain in chains_list_cleaned:
                        if col[6] == chain:
                            atom_chain_outfilepath = "{}_atom_chain_{}.{}".format(fname, chain, ext)
                            with open(atom_chain_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
                                #outfile.writelines("Hello")
                                outfile.writelines(line) # END
    """

cif_code = '1d66'.upper() # CHANGE HERE THE PID CODE. i.e. 1D66, 1QPE, 4TVX

filename = '%s%s.cif' % (cif_dir,cif_code.upper())

begin_atom = get_line_number("_atom_site.group_PDB", filename)
#print begin_atom
my_header_splitfile(filename, begin_atom)
```

If you uncomment the final lines:

```
""" with open(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath,'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()

        rows_list = list()
        chains_list = list()
        for line in lines:
            col = line.split(None)
            rows_list.append(col)
            #print line
            #if col[0] == "HETATM":
            #   print "HETATM record"
            if col[0] == "ATOM":
                #print col[0]
                # LIMITO ALLE SOLE PROTEINE E ACIDI NUCLEICI
                if (col[3] == "N" or col[3] == "N1"):
                    chains_list.append(col[6])
                    chains_list_cleaned = list(set(chains_list))
                    for chain in chains_list_cleaned:
                        if col[6] == chain:
                            atom_chain_outfilepath = "{}_atom_chain_{}.{}".format(fname, chain, ext)
                            with open(atom_chain_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
                                #outfile.writelines("Hello")
                                outfile.writelines(line) # END
"""
```

you will see that I can save a file for each chain (seventh column in the generated '1d66_atom_hetatm.cif' file, for example), but in each file only one line is written, instead of all the lines for that chain (seventh column). How to achieve this?

Thank you,

Riccardo

**EDIT 1:**
You need only to change the line 72, with the downloaded cif file, to test it!

**======================================================================**
**======================================================================**

**EDIT 2:**
This is an example of content in the generated "1D66_atom_hetatm.cif":

```
ATOM   378  C  C8    . DG  A 1 19 ? 34.329 11.346 27.800 1.00 29.46 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C8    1 
ATOM   379  N  N7    . DG  A 1 19 ? 34.046 11.420 26.537 1.00 31.63 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N7    1 
ATOM   380  C  C5    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.698 11.672 26.542 1.00 26.85 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C5    1 
ATOM   381  C  C6    . DG  A 1 19 ? 31.860 11.863 25.447 1.00 26.53 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C6    1 
ATOM   382  O  O6    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.175 11.864 24.251 1.00 32.03 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D O6    1 
ATOM   383  N  N1    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.569 12.079 25.868 1.00 23.18 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N1    1 
ATOM   384  C  C2    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.136 12.115 27.159 1.00 23.53 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C2    1 
ATOM   385  N  N2    . DG  A 1 19 ? 28.819 12.261 27.325 1.00 19.29 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N2    1 
ATOM   386  N  N3    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.949 11.949 28.200 1.00 26.27 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N3    1 
ATOM   387  C  C4    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.213 11.729 27.819 1.00 25.75 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C4    1 
ATOM   388  O  "O5'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 20.466 11.694 21.639 1.00 40.14 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O5'" 1 
ATOM   389  C  "C5'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 21.891 11.609 21.791 1.00 29.52 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C5'" 1 
ATOM   390  C  "C4'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 22.246 11.659 23.274 1.00 28.85 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C4'" 1 
ATOM   391  O  "O4'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 23.643 11.328 23.562 1.00 27.78 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O4'" 1 
ATOM   392  C  "C3'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 22.093 13.078 23.713 1.00 26.83 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C3'" 1 
ATOM   393  O  "O3'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 21.761 13.021 25.064 1.00 26.10 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O3'" 1 
ATOM   394  C  "C2'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 23.541 13.575 23.586 1.00 27.66 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C2'" 1 
ATOM   395  C  "C1'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 24.295 12.435 24.176 1.00 21.82 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C1'" 1
```

I want to save all the rows with A in the seventh column (starting from 0) in a 1d66_A.txt file, and all the rows with B in the seventh column in a 1d66_B.txt file, and so on for all the values for seventh column of that file generated from the script.

Final output should be:

**File 1D66_A.txt:**

```
ATOM   378  C  C8    . DG  A 1 19 ? 34.329 11.346 27.800 1.00 29.46 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C8    1 
ATOM   379  N  N7    . DG  A 1 19 ? 34.046 11.420 26.537 1.00 31.63 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N7    1 
ATOM   380  C  C5    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.698 11.672 26.542 1.00 26.85 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C5    1 
ATOM   381  C  C6    . DG  A 1 19 ? 31.860 11.863 25.447 1.00 26.53 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C6    1 
ATOM   382  O  O6    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.175 11.864 24.251 1.00 32.03 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D O6    1 
ATOM   383  N  N1    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.569 12.079 25.868 1.00 23.18 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N1    1 
ATOM   384  C  C2    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.136 12.115 27.159 1.00 23.53 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C2    1 
ATOM   385  N  N2    . DG  A 1 19 ? 28.819 12.261 27.325 1.00 19.29 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N2    1 
ATOM   386  N  N3    . DG  A 1 19 ? 30.949 11.949 28.200 1.00 26.27 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D N3    1 
ATOM   387  C  C4    . DG  A 1 19 ? 32.213 11.729 27.819 1.00 25.75 ? ? ? ? ? ? 19  DG  D C4    1
```

**File 1D66_B.txt:**

```
ATOM   388  O  "O5'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 20.466 11.694 21.639 1.00 40.14 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O5'" 1 
ATOM   389  C  "C5'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 21.891 11.609 21.791 1.00 29.52 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C5'" 1 
ATOM   390  C  "C4'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 22.246 11.659 23.274 1.00 28.85 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C4'" 1 
ATOM   391  O  "O4'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 23.643 11.328 23.562 1.00 27.78 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O4'" 1 
ATOM   392  C  "C3'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 22.093 13.078 23.713 1.00 26.83 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C3'" 1 
ATOM   393  O  "O3'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 21.761 13.021 25.064 1.00 26.10 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "O3'" 1 
ATOM   394  C  "C2'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 23.541 13.575 23.586 1.00 27.66 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C2'" 1 
ATOM   395  C  "C1'" . DC  B 2 1  ? 24.295 12.435 24.176 1.00 21.82 ? ? ? ? ? ? 20  DC  E "C1'" 1
```

**I'm trying to explain myself in the best way, sorry, and Thanks for your help.**

The steps are concatenated, so I can't split the script: You can try it... The problem is simply that I want to obtain what was said in the Edit 2 that is, reading the 6th column (starting from 0, where you read AAAAAAABBBBBB, in that example), copy all the rows that contain the A in a file named "1d66_A.txt" and all the rows that contain B, in another text file "1d66_B.txt", like in the Edit 2. To test what I have done, simply copy and paste that script into a text file with the extension .py (eg. my_script.py); in the same folder of that script, create a folder "cif" and put in it a cif file (1d66, for example, if you don't want to edit the 72th line of the script) downloaded from those links; finally run the script in a shell with the command "python my_script.py" (I'm using Linux): the script generates four files. In this topic I refer myself to the generated "1d66_atom_hetatm.cif" file, which I want to split as I said, in "1d66_A.txt", "1d66_B.txt", "1d66_C.txt", "1d66_D.txt" (4 files, because in 1d66 there are 4 different letters in the 6th column (starting from 0) of all rows that start with ATOM), for example, as in **EDIT 2**.

**======================================================================**
**======================================================================**

**EDIT 3 - @qwwqwwq**

I will try to explain the script with words; suppose this sequence:

> **HHHHH**LLLLL**AAAAA**BBBBB**FFFFF**

This is a scheme of the starting point and the end point of a CIF file which I have done to me, to rationalize a cif file before to elaborate it in python, where:

```
H = header
L = loop for ATOM and HETATM rows
A = chain A (= column 7) in ATOM 
B = chain B (= column 7) in ATOM 
F = footer
```

Now, I need to split all these sections of a generic cif file; to do that, I'm writing this script, that for now can generate:

```
H
L
A+B
F
```

So I need to split A from B yet!
Why I used a temporary file? Let me explain; these the steps:

1. check where is the LOOP for ATOM and HETATM rows. To do that, I search the string "_atom_site.group_PDB" (last three lines in the script) and I get the relative line number with the function "get_line_number". I know that loop has a lenght of 26 rows, so now I know where it starts and ends (start = begin_atom = output of "get_line_number" function; end = 26 rows after begin_atom, that are 25, because "range" starts from 0, while get_line_number function starts from 1). So, now I can save the loop in a separated file.
2. I can save the header (H) too, because it starts from line 0 to the line "begin_atom" (output of "get_line_number" function)
3. Now, for A, B and F I made use of that temporary file (temporary, because I remove it at last). I generated the temporary file from the end of the loop [=("begin_atom"+26), that is 25 because the range starts from 0] to the end of the file (line "-1"), and I save it as temporary file, used as input to write the footer (F); how to do that? Using the construct:

   `if not (line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('HETATM'))`

   so I can save the footer too now!
4. Now it remains to split all the chains (colums 7) in the record that starts with ATOM and HETATM, for which I opened this topic. I thought what I have written in the edit 2. In reality, the chains (column 7) can be only one (as in file 1QPE) or many (as in the 4TVX file, where there are 22 chains, that is 22 different letters in the column 7 of each row which starts with ATOM or HETATM).

I tried in that commented way in my script (see before the **EDIT 1**), which saves a file for each chain (different letter in column 7), but in each file only an ATOM row is written..... I hope I have expressed myself clearly and correctly

**======================================================================**
**======================================================================**

**SOLVED - THANKS TO @qwwqwwq**

@qwwqwwq :-) Thank You. I was looking always in the "cif" folder for the output, without realizing that, after the small edits to your code (see my edit), the script was saving files in its same folder :-D. Perfect!

The final version in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
import os.path
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cif_dir = os.path.join(scriptdir, 'cif/')

def get_line_number(phrase, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if phrase in line:
                return i

def my_header_splitfile(infilepath, chunksize):
    fname, ext = infilepath.rsplit('.',1)
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        outfilepath = "{}_header.{}".format(fname, ext)
        with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in (infile.readline() for _ in range(0,(chunksize-2))):
                outfile.write(line) # END
    temp_lines = open(infilepath).readlines()
    temp_outfilepath = "{}_temp.{}".format(fname, ext)
    atom_hetatm_header_outfilepath = "{}_atom_hetatm_header.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(temp_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(temp_lines[(chunksize+25):-1]) # END
    with open(atom_hetatm_header_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(temp_lines[(chunksize-2):(chunksize+25)])
    footer_lines = open(temp_outfilepath).readlines()
    footer_outfilepath = "{}_footer.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(footer_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in footer_lines:
            if not (line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('HETATM')):
                outfile.writelines(line) # END
    temp_atom_hetatm_lines = open(temp_outfilepath).readlines()
    temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath = "{}_atom_hetatm.{}".format(fname, ext)
    with open(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in temp_atom_hetatm_lines:
            if (line.startswith('ATOM') or line.startswith('HETATM')):
                outfile.writelines(line) # END
    """NEW ENTRY"""
    with open(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("ATOM"):
                atom_chain_outfilepath = "{}_atom_chain_{}.{}".format(fname, line.split()[6], ext)
                with open(atom_chain_outfilepath, "a") as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("HETATM"):
                atom_chain_outfilepath = "{}_hetatm_chain_{}.{}".format(fname, line.split()[6], ext)
                with open(atom_chain_outfilepath, "a") as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)
    os.remove(temp_outfilepath) # REMOVE "temp_outfilepath"
    os.remove(temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath) # REMOVE "temp_atom_hetatm_outfilepath" - FINISH

cif_code = '1d66'.upper() # CHANGE HERE THE PID CODE. i.e. 1D66, 1QPE, 4TVX

filename = '%s%s.cif' % (cif_dir,cif_code.upper())

begin_atom = get_line_number("_atom_site.group_PDB", filename)
#print begin_atom
my_header_splitfile(filename, begin_atom)
```

Now you need to edit the 55th row for the PID entry (i.e. 1d66, 1qpe, 4tvx, ..., downloaded from the Protein Data Bank).

Comment: Rather than a link elsewhere, could you put a little bit of sample data in the question itself so we have something to test with?

Comment: @AdamSmith But you can download it... the script works on the whole original file!

Comment: Until the link goes away. Link rot is real, and stackoverflow is intended to be a permanent (-ish) repository of programming information. Please update your question with sample data pasted in.

Comment: @AdamSmith But that is the Protein Data Bank

Comment: While this is probably a great question, there is a ton of code here. Is it possible to reduce the code down to just what you are looking to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very hard to tell what you are asking here, sorry for that. Providing sample input and output that fits within the body of your question would go a long way.

It sounds like you want to split a file based on the values in the sixth column of the file.

I would do something like:

```
def meets_criteria(line):
  return line.startswith("ATOM") or line.startswith("HETATM")

with open(large_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if meets_criteria(line):
            with open(line.split()[6], "a") as of:
                of.write(line)
```

So you would have files named after the values in the 6th column (0 indexed).

You seem to be using the `.readlines` method a lot, be aware this reads all of the data into memory, there is no reason to do this and it could be why your script is hanging on big input.

Comment: it seems necessary to use readlines for a correct execution of the script, otherwise some files result empty as content...

Comment: my guess is that you are opening paths for writing multiple times, and thus clobbering your output files, that is why you get empty files or files with just one line

Comment: Hi qwwqwwq, Thanks for your suggestion. I saw that "rows = infile.readlines()" at line 20 is sure an error, also because it's not used in the script. Probably it's a residue of many rearrangements :-)

Comment: yes, also i don't get what you are doing with temporary files in your code, you shouldn't need a temporary file if you avoid using `readlines()`